# Word shading text not working for spaces before line break

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-word-2016

In Word `Home>Paragraph>Shading`, I would like to shade scripts similar to what we have for in-line quote in Stack exchange `/home/xxx/`

I realized that if the shading is just before line break, I cannot extend it to cover some more space after the text end. The result is something like this, with ugly shading not covering all text

[image]

If the text is in the middle of the sentence, there is no problem to extend the shading into the white space

[image]

Any idea how I can fix the first case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an idiosyncrasy of Word that you can apply Highlighting to
a space character only if one or more visible text characters are found
*before and after* it.

One workaround for this limitation is to add an invisible character after the blank.
The character to use is the weird
[zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space),
whose unicode encoding is `200b`, or in decimal `8203`.
Fortunately, Word treats it as a printable character.

This is how to type it after the blank on a desktop keyboard:

- Ensure that NumLock is On
- Press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and don't release it
- Use the NumPad key to type `8203`
- Release the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key

On a keyboard that doesn't have a NumPad, you will need to use the On-Screen Keyboard
(osk.exe).

Now select the text and the following blank (be careful not to select the
zero-width space) and apply the shading.

Comment: Amazing how Word still has that kind of limitation in 2019. Another thing I'd like to have is shading on the padding before and after paragraph similar to https://developers.google.com/style/code-in-text . Currently no matter if I format paragraph to have space before or after, the shading will not cover that part. I am manually inserting empty lines to achieve that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the problem with padding. Perhaps it should be placed in a separate post (drop me a note here).

Comment: Could you just put your code into a borderless, shaded table cell instead?  That way shading is on cell not the paragraph which avoids the issue with paragraph spacing before and after not being shaded.